# Is it possible to make images clickable to show the full image file?

Tags: support, questions, answers

When adding screenshots they get downsized to max 630px, sometimes rendering the text unreadable. Right clicking and opening the image in a new tab reveals the image in original size. Is it possible to link the 630px 'thumbnails' to the full size images?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely, but you need to add the link manually as the toolbar doesn't have that functionality.

Taken from [What's the recommended syntax for an image with a link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/whats-the-recommended-syntax-for-an-image-with-a-link), the syntax looks like this:

```
[![alt text][2]][1]

  [1]: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/44330/jason-s
  [2]: http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dd57e..dfd07?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG (hover text)
```

Comment: Unclear to me, how to do manually?, Can you explain more. meaning the steps

Comment: @Bala Click the image link as normal, you'll get something like `![alt text][2]` - then wrap that in another markdown link which is done like this: `[...linkcontent...][1]`. That gives you something along the lines of `[![alt text][2]][1]`